# Could someone help me to derive the closed form for this sum?

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, summation

$$\sum_{r=1}^n  \frac{(-1)^{r+1}(r+2)}{2^{r+1}}$$

I've already looked on Wolfram Alpha for the solution but I would like to know the step-by-step process to get there. I've attempted to make this into a telescoping sum but it seems to fail due to the alternating nature. I would greatly appreciate it if someone could help me with a method.

Answer (score 4):

Hint: $\sum\limits_{r=1}^{n} x^{r+2}(-1)^{r+1}$ is a geometric sum with common ratio $-x$. If you differentiate this you  get $\sum\limits_{r=1}^{n} (r+2)x^{r+1}(-1)^{r+1}$. Put $x=\frac  1 2$.

Comment: Thanks! I believe I used the hint to come to the correct answer but I don't understand why we multiply by 2. Could you clarify?

Comment: Sorry, that was a mistake. No need to multiply by $2$. @ShafinAlam

Comment: No problem, thanks so much for helping me out.

Answer (score 4):

**HINT**: $$\sum_{r=1}^n\dfrac{(-1)^{r+1}(r+2)}{2 ^{r+1}}=\underbrace{\sum_{r=1}^nr\left(\frac{-1}{2}\right) ^{r+1}}_S+\underbrace{2\sum_{r=1}^n \left(\frac{-1}{2}\right) ^{r+1} }_T$$

#### For S:

$$S= \left(\frac{-1}{2}\right) ^2+2 \left(\frac{-1}{2}\right) ^ 3+3 \left(\frac{-1}{2}\right) ^ 4+… +n\left(\frac{-1}{2}\right) ^{n+1} $$$$\frac{-S}{2}=\ \ \ \ \quad\qquad  \ \ \left(\frac{-1}{2}\right) ^3+2 \left(\frac{-1}{2}\right) ^4+3 \left(\frac{-1}{2}\right) ^5+…+n \left(\frac{-1}{2}\right) ^{n+2}$$ Subtract like powers of $\left(\dfrac{-1}{2}\right)$ to get $$\dfrac{3S}{2}=\left(\text{G.P. with ratio $\left(\dfrac{-1}{2}\right)$}\right)- n 
\left(\dfrac{-1}{2}\right)^{n+2}$$

#### For T:

It is a simple GP.

Comment: Thanks! It's quite beautiful how this method works out and I can follow it easily but I'd like to ask you what motivated you to get -S/2. Unless I had previous experience with a similar question, I wouldn't think of doing this.

Comment: This is a standard method of computing an [Arithmetic-Geometric Series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetico%E2%80%93geometric_sequence) where you multiply the sum with the common ratio and subtract. You can try to solve these with a similar approach: $$A=\frac{1}{2}+ \frac{2}{2^2}+ \frac{3}{2^3}+ \frac{4}{2^4} + \frac{5}{2^5}+…+ \frac{n}{2^n}$$ and $$B= \frac{-1}{2}+ \frac{2 }{4}-\frac{3}{8}+ \frac{4}{16}-… +(-1)^n \frac{n}{2^n}$$.

Comment: Thank you so much, I'll get to doing these right now. I actually did see an Arithmetic-Geometric series being summed in a video some time ago but it seems like I didn't fully get it then. Thanks for adding this method to my arsenal.